# definir variables dinamicas en jQuery, con Thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, materialize, thymeleaf

Buenas,
Estoy tratando de llamar de forma dinámica a los "id" en los tags con el "th:each", de la siguiente manera.

```
<div th:each="alumno : ${alumnos}" class="row" th:id="'card_' + ${alumno.id}" style="display: none">
    <div class="col s12 m10">
        <div class="card black darken-1">
            <div class="card-content lime-text text-darken-1">
                <span class="card-title" th:text="${alumno.nombres} + ' ' + ${alumno.apellidos}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        $('#show_[${alumno.id}]]').click(function () {
            $('#card_[${alumno.id}]]').fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
        });

        /*]]>*/


    </script>
</div>
```

el resultado que espero(en **jQuery** ), de forma iterada,  sería el siguiente:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        $('#close_EclairLast').click(function () {
            $('#card123').fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
        });

        $('#show_1').click(function () {
            $('#card_1').fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" ); //aqui seria card_[1...n]
        });

        /*]]>*/


    </script>
```

existe alguna manera de por concatenar el valor del objeto ${alumno.id} en jquery para que sea dinamico???

Los id="show_n" genero tambien dinámicamente en una tabla...

```
<table class="striped grey lighten-5">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CI</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="alumno : ${alumnos}">
            <td th:text="${alumno.cedula}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.nombres}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.apellidos}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.telefono}">0971490111</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn-floating light-blue darken-4" th:id="'show_' + ${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a>
                <a class="btn-floating light-green darken-4" th:id="'edit_' + ${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
                <a class="btn-floating red darken-4" th:id="'remove_' + ${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Saludos.-

Comment: Hola @Edu! Bienvenido a StackOverflow, se me ocurren un par de cosas que podrías hacer, algunas evitando tener que replicar tantas veces esa etiqueta `script`. No obstante, antes de proponer nada me ha surgido una duda. Donde se encuentra ese elemento con id `#show_n`? No lo veo en el código que nos pasas.

Comment: Hola @frikinside , gracias por contestar... Actualicé el código en donde genero los el elemento `#show_n` , creo que ahí se entiende mejor lo que quiero hacer, agradecido desde ya!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, creo que me respondré a mi mismo....

El camino que encontré para la solución fue el de agregarle a mis botones una nueva clase, "showdetalle" , y asi crear una función que utilice esa nueva clase...
el código html quedó así

```
<table class="striped grey lighten-5">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CI</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="alumno : ${alumnos}">
            <td th:text="${alumno.cedula}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.nombres}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.apellidos}"></td>
            <td th:text="${alumno.telefono}"></td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn-floating light-blue darken-4 showdetalle" th:id="'show_' + ${alumno.id}" th:value="${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a> <!-- aqui se agrego la clase "showdetalle" -->
                <a class="btn-floating light-green darken-4" th:id="'edit_' + ${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
                <a class="btn-floating red darken-4" th:id="'remove_' + ${alumno.id}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<div th:each="alumno : ${alumnos}" class="row" th:id="'card_' + ${alumno.id}" style="display: none">
    <div class="col s12 m10">
        <div class="card black darken-1">
            <div class="card-content lime-text text-darken-1">
                <span class="card-title"  th:inline="text" >
                    <b> [[${alumno.nombres}]] [[${alumno.apellidos}]] - [[${alumno.grupoSanguineo}]] </b> <a class="btn-floating black closedetalle" th:id="'close_' + ${alumno.id}" style="float: right; vertical-align: top;"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" th:inline="text">
                <span class="white-text">
                    <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">CI:</span> [[${alumno.cedula}]] <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Fecha de Nacimiento:</span> [[${alumno.fechaNacimiento}]] <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Estado Civil:</span> [[${alumno.estadoCivil}]]<br/>
                    <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">email: </span> [[${alumno.email}]] <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">telefono:</span> [[${alumno.telefono}]] <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Nacionalidad:</span> [[${alumno.nacionalidad}]]<br/>
                    <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Direccion:</span> Calle1 y calle 2 - Asuncion<br/>
                </span>
                <span class="lime-text text-darken-1"><b>Contacto de Emergencia: [[${alumno.contactoEmergenciaNombre}]] - [[${alumno.contactoEmergenciaparentesco}]]</b></span><br/>
                <span class="white-text">
                    <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Contacto:</span> [[${alumno.contactoEmergenciaTelefono}]] <span class="lime-text text-darken-1">Seguro Medico:</span> [[${alumno.contactoEmergenciaSeguroMedico}]]
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

y cree las siguientes funciones con jQuery:

```
$('.showdetalle').click(function () {
    var elId = $(this).attr('id');
    elId = elId.replace('show_', '#card_');
    console.log(elId);

   $(elId).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );

 });
$('.closedetalle').click(function () {
    var elId2 = $(this).attr('id');
    elId2 = elId2.replace('close_', '#card_');
    console.log(elId2);

    $(elId2).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );

});
```

así quedo mi código para realizar la funcion de "ocultar" y "mostrar"... gracias desde ya.-

Comment: Justo esa posibilidad era una de las que te iba a comentar. No es muy "elegante" pero es funcional. Otra posibilidad que te iba a comentar era la de utilizar un atributo propio `data-idalumno` para que almacenaras ahí el  `id` y no tuvieras que hacer reemplazos de cadenas. Te lo comento por si quieres probar ese acercamiento también o incluso añadirlo a la respuesta. Por cierto, si esta respuesta (aunque sea tuya también) resuelve tu problema, marcala como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

tambien lo puedes hacer de esta manera saludos

```
  <th:block th:each="condicionComercial : ${CondicionesComerciales}">
                              <tr>
                                 <td><img th:src="@{${'/images/operadores/' + condicionComercial.idOperador + '.png'}}" width="30" height="30"/></td>
                                 <td th:text="${condicionComercial.restriccion}"></td>
                              </tr>
                           </th:block>
```

saludos